# Xampp Apache server won't start?

Tags: kali-linux, php, xampp

I have recently installed Xammp onto my laptop which runs Kali Linux. The MySQL server & ProFTPD server both run fine.

The Application log looks like:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
httpd: Syntax error on line 136 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /opt/lampp/modules/mod_ssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help?

How do I get the missing file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on Ubuntu. I ended up uninstalling XAMPP 7.0.9 and installing 7.0.8 and now it works fine.

To uninstall:

```
cd /opt/lampp  
sudo ./uninstall
```